# Python: Trying to convert string to datetime

Tags: python, string, datetime

This is my code

```
import datetime
str = "2020-12-24 14:05:56.449122"
e = datetime.datetime.strptime(str, '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
print(e)
```

It shows this error--

> time data '2020-12-24 14:05:56.449122' does not match format '%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f

Comment: `%y` is 2-digit year, `%Y` is 4-digit year.

Comment: Use `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat`